# Difference between the classes BrowseFragment and BrowseSupportFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tv, browsefragment

What is the difference between the classes **BrowseFragment** and **BrowseSupportFragment** as mentioned in the android developer documentation?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/package-summary.html

Most of the methods and documentation is same for both the classes, so from documentation it's really difficult to figure out which class to use according to the use cases.

Can someone please help to understand the difference between these classes and guide to choose with some example use cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BrowseSupportFragment** extends from root `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` which is `static` library support version of the framework's `android.app.Fragment`. Used to write apps that run on platforms prior to `Android 3.0.` When running on `Android 3.0` or above, this implementation is still used; it does not try to switch to the framework's `android.app.Fragment` implementation.

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html)

Comment: what do you mean by "it does not try to switch to the framework's implementation."

Comment: android.support.v4.app.Fragment does not try to switch to the framework's android.app.Fragment implementation

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thanks.

Comment: If my answer seems useful and if you got desired answer then you can accept this answer.

Comment: Simply put, if your app is for Android 3.0+, ignore all \*Support* classes from the leanback library, as they are duplicates for compatibility reasons.

Comment: If you are using *BrowseSupportFragment* you have to Extend your activity with FragmentActivity.